# How to set the layer attribute for IDW interpolation tool within a QGIS Python script

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-3, interpolation

I have a custom Python script in QGIS 3.10 that integrates some QGIS tools. One of them is the IDW interpolation tool. My issue is I don't know how to properly set the layer attribute to be used for the interpolation.

```
# file connections
infile = os.path.join(scratch_folder, "lakes.shp")
lakes_meta = QFileInfo(infile)
lakes_title = lakes_meta.baseName()
lakes_layer = QgsVectorLayer(infile, lakes_title, 'ogr')

# run IDW interpolation tool
processing.run('qgis:idwinterpolation',
                {'INTERPOLATION_DATA': lakes_layer,   ### < --- how to specify layer attribute???
                 'DISTANCE_COEFFICIENT': 2,
                 'EXTENT': lakes_layer,
                 'PIXEL_SIZE':1,
                 'OUTPUT': os.path.join(scratch_folder, 'IDW_output.tif')})
```

The QGIS documentation alludes to the use of either `'::|::'` or `'::~::'` to assign the correct column for interpolation, but I've never used anything formatted like that before and am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is to run the algorithm via the gui from the processing toolbox first. Then check the processing history (clock icon at top of processing toolbox) to access the syntax for its Python call.

E.g. you will see something like:

[image]

This can be simplified a bit, so for your code you could do something like:

```
infile = os.path.join(scratch_folder, "lakes.shp")
lakes_meta = QFileInfo(infile)
lakes_title = lakes_meta.baseName()
lakes_layer = QgsVectorLayer(infile, lakes_title, 'ogr')

# run IDW interpolation tool
processing.run('qgis:idwinterpolation',
                {'INTERPOLATION_DATA':'{}::~::0::~::2::~::0'.format(infile), # Copy ::~::0::~::2::~::0 from processing history
                 'DISTANCE_COEFFICIENT': 2,
                 'EXTENT': lakes_layer.extent(),
                 'PIXEL_SIZE':1, # Pixel size of 1m may be very slow to write!
                 'OUTPUT': os.path.join(scratch_folder, 'IDW_output.tif')})
```

Comment: That can also be found in the 'log' section of the tool window when you run it in the GUI (I realized after trying to skip over that portion of my code by manually running the tool). Thanks for the answer and for the helpful additions to my code too!

Comment: No worries @Rob, cheers.